# Unknown strange syntax

Tags: search-engine

So recently I have been playing around with yacy the p2p search engine. I came across this strange syntax in their html pages looks like some type of include, am not sure exactly what it does (or what language it is). here's the code.

```
#(num-results)#
::
<p>No Results.</p>
::
<p>No Results. (length of search words must be at least 1 character)</p>
::
<div id="results"></div>
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" id="progressbar" role="progressbar" style="width:0%;">
    <span style="position:absolute;display:block;text-align:left;width:100%;color:black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong id="offset">#[offset]#</strong>-<strong id="itemscount">#[itemscount]#</strong> of <strong id="totalcount">#[totalcount]#</strong> #(globalresults)#::; (<strong id="localResourceSize">#[localResourceSize]#</strong> local, <strong id="remoteResourceSize">#[remoteResourceSize]#</strong> remote), <strong id="remoteIndexCount">#[remoteIndexCount]#</strong> from <strong id="remotePeerCount">#[remotePeerCount]#</strong> remote YaCy peers.#(/globalresults)#</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

What does the #(*somename*)# and #[*somename*]# syntax do? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely nothing. but you could parse it with javascript and replace it with values.

Its no official language. its their own implementation to manipulate html output.
Which can be done server side or client side. They kinda make up the rules and you can decide by styling where the values should appear.

In my example I replace #[itemscount]# by an arbitrary 10

```js
str = '<span style="position:absolute;display:block;text-align:left;width:100%;color:black;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong id="offset">#[offset]#</strong>-<strong id="itemscount">#[itemscount]#</strong> of <strong id="totalcount">#[totalcount]#</strong> #(globalresults)#::; (<strong id="localResourceSize">#[localResourceSize]#</strong> local, <strong id="remoteResourceSize">#[remoteResourceSize]#</strong> remote), <strong id="remoteIndexCount">#[remoteIndexCount]#</strong> from <strong id="remotePeerCount">#[remotePeerCount]#</strong> remote YaCy peers.#(/globalresults)#</span>';

document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = str.replace('#[itemscount]#',"10");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```